# parsing lists of integers to vector or map or multimap?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a list in the following format:

```
2323 0 1212
2424 0 1313
2525 1 1414
```

I need to store every row of these values and I need the possibility to access each of them individually and to be able to search for the occurrence of any number which is stored in whatever I use.

What can I use? Should I use multiple vectors or can I store them in a multimap or maybe a boost::tuple?

I can't use c++11 and I have only limited boost support (1.36 is installed and I can't update).

I already have a parser which can parse the list (found it there):http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/parser.html

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use three `unordered_map`s: one for each column, and holding pointers to some storage of e.g. a tuple containing the three numbers. This may be huge overkill though. How do you handle duplicate numbers?

Comment: What do the rows represent? Sounds like maybe you could use a `struct` that gives a meaningful name to each of the three values and then keep a 1d `vector` of those?

Comment: I don't really care about duplicate numbers, important is just the row itself (containing three integers)

Comment: the first is the position right now the second a direction and the third the next reachable position

Comment: [Boost multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Comment: Next time, search StackOverflow first.  A good search in this case is "c++ read value from file" or "c++ read file array" or "c++ read file structure".

Comment: If any of these answers solved your problem, please mark the appropriate one as "accepted" by clicking the tick next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could define a struct (taking names from your comment):

```
struct Item
{
    int position;
    int direction;
    int nextPosition;
};
```

And then just have an `std::vector<Item>`. The row would be the index. To count the occurrence of a value, you can pass a custom predicate to `std::count` or just define your own function to do so, as I think using std::count without C++11 lambdas might be a bit difficult.

EDIT: To make things easier for you, as suggested by Thomas Matthews, you could overload operator>> for your struct to read directly from a file:

```
struct Item
{
    int position;
    int direction;
    int nextPosition;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Item& item);
};

std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& stream, Item& item)
{
    stream >> item.position  >> item.direction >> item.nextPosition;

    return stream;
}
```

Comment: A nicety would be to add support for input by overloading `operator>>` in the structure.

Comment: Thank you, I did it the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want to do with it. A vector of vectors would work to access all numbers and keep them row-by-row. That would also preserve the ordering of the numbers within the rows. You can find numbers by walking through the vectors (or use the STL find functions which do the same)

If you need to insert or delete rows/numbers, you might consider a list instead of a vector. Lists have better performance for insert/delete but you lose random access.

If you just need to know whether specific numbers exist, then you might put them into a multiset. You will lose the ability to know in which row a number is and also you lose the ordering of the numbers within the rows.

Answer (score 0):

It might be fastest (although I haven't tested it) to simply throw the numbers into a `std::vector`, one after the other, totally ignoring the row structure, and just step through the whole thing to detect a match at index `i`. You can then get the row with a bit of index wrangling as `( i % 3 ) + {0|1|2}`.

Comment: Usually, if you are reading from a file, there is no reason for speed.  The numbers have to be converted from their textual representation to internal representation regardless.  If the file access was immediate, the conversion process would take up the remaining time.  I believe the structure would be more readable and beneficial.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: true, file ops are slow. I didn't interpret the question as reading the list from a file, I thought they were to be stored and handled in some sort of structure in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

If you can safely assume that every row always has 3 columns, then use a `std::vector<int>`. Then when you want to know the row/column that a number originated from, you can use a function like this:

```
bool find( const std::vector<int>& numbers, int target, int& row, int& column )
{
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::find( numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), target );

    if( it == numbers.end() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    int index = it - numbers.begin();
    row = index / 3;
    column = index % 3;

    return true;
}

// Example:
std::vector<int> numbers = ...
int row, column;

if( find( numbers, 10, row, column ) )
{
    std::cout << "Found at row " << row << ", column " << column << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
}
```